# Adding a user to many-to-many field by default

Tags: django, django-forms

I have the following class:

```
class Module(models.Model):
    contributors = models.ManyToManyField(User)
```

What I'd like to do is when I save a ModelForm using this class, the user that submitted the form would be saved to the contributors field. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First approach:

```
def moduleForm( request ):

    formset_f = modelformset_factory(  Module, extra=20 )
    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = formset_f(request.POST)
        if formset.is_valid():            
            for form in formset:
                module = form.save()
                module.contributors.add( request.user )
                ...
```

Comment: I was thinking this was how I was going to have to go about it, but wasn't sure. I'll give it a shot. Thanks.